# Outputs printed on same line - python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

```
message = str(input())
for i in message:
  if i == " ":
    print(" ")
  else:
    # ord(i) returns the ASCII number for i
    # To get the actual alphabetical position of i, you have to do ASCII of letter - ASCII of A + 1.
    print(ord(i)-ord("a")+1)
```

This program converts each character of the users input to a letter, based on their alphabetical order (a = 1, b = 2, ect) and prints each number output on a new line. How do I get change this so that when each number is printed, it is on the same line as the last? (eg 123)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the optional `end` argument to `""` in `print()` as:

```
print(ord(i)-ord("a")+1, end="")
```

Comment: @KrishanaChaurasia I'm getting a bad  input error message when I try this?

Comment: did you add the other part of the code as well? you need the full code with the `print()` statement updated as above.

Comment: it could also be because of the input you tried, can you add the input you tried?

Comment: @KrishinaChaurasia print(ord(i)-ord("a")+1, end="") Yes, I added the whole code. I haven't tried any input with this because the error message comes up as soon as I try to run the code (I am using a software that won't let the code run if there is a bad input on a specific line)

Comment: I am not sure, I suspect some other problem. What if you just run `print('Hello', end='')` `print('World')`?

Comment: I tried this and still got an error message - I realised the software I'm using was using a version older than python 3 and I'm sure that must've been the issue. Thank you SO much for the help, though!

Answer (score 0):

Use this
print("what ever you want to print",end= " ")

It will print without taking the cursor down a line.